# Setup multiple expectations on a method in Rhino.Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, expect

What's the correct way to setup multiple expectations on a method if you need a different return value for each consecutive invocation in [Rhino.Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) V3.6?

The following code used to work in V3.5 but fails in V3.6.

```
public void Test()
{
    var mocks = new MockRepository();

    var process = mocks.DynamicMock<IProcess>();
    Expect.Call(process.Run()).Return(1);
    Expect.Call(process.Run()).Return(2);

    mocks.ReplayAll();

    Assert.That(process.Run(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(process.Run(), Is.EqualTo(2));

    mocks.VerifyAll();
}

public interface IProcess
{
    int Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way - but it works :)

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(new [] {1, 2, 3});
var mockObject = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IdGenerator>();
mockObject.Expect(calc => calc.GetNext())
          .Do( (Func<int>) queue.Dequeue);

Console.Out.WriteLine(mockObject.GetNext()); // returns 1
Console.Out.WriteLine(mockObject.GetNext()); // returns 2
Console.Out.WriteLine(mockObject.GetNext()); // returns 3
```

The last time I needed this I created [an extension method](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#K75vIOKIHNQ/trunk/Beacons/Test.Beacons/Infrastructure/MoqExtensions.cs&q=returnsnextvalue%20package%3ahttp://gishu-util%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc) (although for Moq). Worked out pretty well for me..

```
_mockClock.Setup(clock => clock.GetCurrentTime())
          .ReturnsNextValueFrom(transitionTimestamps);
```

Comment: I crossed posted on the Rhino.Mocks forums after not getting an answer here and it turns out I needed to add `.Repeat.Once()` to restore the older 3.5 behavior. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Feel free to update your answer with my actual solution (for the benefit of others) and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Nathan - I'm not aware of the the Repeat.Once trick; so would be wrong to take credit for it. Copy-paste the answer from the forums as an answer here. Accept it (nothing wrong with answering your own questions if you figured it out yourself)